# Asymptote: How do I make a gap in a segment to include a label?

Tags: asymptote

I am wondering how to make a gap in a segment to include a label? In my example code, I'd ideally like the label '16' to be in a gap the middle of the end-barred segment.

Also, is there a more efficient way to format the end-barred segment so that it runs parallel to the segment that it measures?

Thanks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{asymptote}

\begin{document}

\begin{asy}
import olympiad;
import cse5;
size(4cm);
pair G,T,P,Q,A,B;
G=(0,0); T=(9,0); P=(16,0); Q=(9,-7.937);A=(0,2); B=(16,2);
draw(G--Q--P--G);
draw(Q--T);
draw(A--B, Bars);
draw(rightanglemark(G,T,Q,45));
draw(rightanglemark(P,Q,G,45));
label("$y$",align=N,point(G--T,0.5));
label("$12$",align=SW,point(G--Q,0.5));
label("$16$",midpoint(A--B),N);
\end{asy}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! On p. 42 of [this nice tutorial](https://math.uchicago.edu/~cstaats/Charles_Staats_III/Notes_and_papers_files/asymptote_tutorial.pdf) there seems to be an example. (I do not have `olympiad.asy`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost literally copied from the example on p. 42 of [this nice tutorial](https://math.uchicago.edu/~cstaats/Charles_Staats_III/Notes_and_papers_files/asymptote_tutorial.pdf). I also prefer to use the `asypictureB` style by the author of the manual. With this, you only need to run `pdflatex -shell-escape` on

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{asypictureB}

\begin{document}

\begin{asypicture}{name=Label}
import olympiad;
//import cse5;
size(4cm);
pair G,T,P,Q,A,B;
G=(0,0); T=(9,0); P=(16,0); Q=(9,-7.937);A=(0,2); B=(16,2);
draw(G--Q--P--G);
draw(Q--T);
draw(rightanglemark(G,T,Q,45));
draw(rightanglemark(P,Q,G,45));
label("$y$",align=N,point(G--T,0.5));
label("$12$",align=SW,point(G--Q,0.5));
//label("$16$",midpoint(A--B),N);
pen fillpen = white;
Label mylabel = Label("$16$", align=(0,0), position=MidPoint,
filltype=Fill(fillpen));
draw(A--B, L=mylabel, Bars);
\end{asypicture}

\end{document}
```

to get

[image]

Note that downloaded `olympiad.asy` from [this web site](http://web.evanchen.cc/olympiad.html). `cse5.asy` was not needed.

Comment: marmot...thank you! I have referred to this tutorial in the past and must have overlooked this example. I also really appreciate your feedback on streamlining my code.

Comment: For the question about the end-barred statement: you can eliminate `A` and `B`, replacing `A -- B` with `shift(0,2) * (G -- P)`.

Comment: @CharlesStaats Thanks a lot! Would you like to add an answer? This would be more appropriate because all I did was to copy something from your manual. (I will be happy to remove my post then.)

Comment: Seeing others quote my tutorial is far more gratifying to me than getting reputation points. :) Besides, I've gotten rusty in TeX/Asymptote since leaving academia, so chances are you answered the labeling question more easily than I could have. (As much as I love TeX, it's hard to justify when your company's workflow is built around Google Docs and markdown.)

Comment: @CharlesStaats Thanks for jumping into the thread. I've been writing some seriously inelegant code; I'm so grateful for your pointer that utilizes the power of TeX/Asymptote rather that relying on figuring out the geometry of the figures by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to use `geometry.asy` which provides `markrightangle` and a `distance` routine.
Please find the code

```
  import geometry;
  size(4cm);
  pair G,T,P,Q;
  G=(0,0); T=(9,0); P=(16,0); Q=(9,-7.937);
  draw(G--Q--P--G);
  draw(Q--T);
  perpendicularmark(T, dir(-135));
  markrightangle(P,Q,G);
  label("$y$",align=N,point(G--T,0.5));
  label("$12$",align=SW,point(G--Q,0.5));

  distance("$16$",G,P,-6mm);
```

and the result

[image]